# How to pass an ImageView which is selected from the internal Storage between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, send

I uploaded an Image from my Internal Storage and want now to pass this
selected Image to a new Activity. I do not pass an Image from the
drawable. I pass an Image which I selected from my Internal Storage. I
tried to pass this Image via the R.id

```
ImageView imageView_selectedImage;

imageView_selectedImage =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_selectedImage);

Button button_goToNextActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_goToNextActivity);

button_goToNextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("resId", R.id.selectedImage);
       startActivity(intent);
      }
}
```

Comment: You are a bit confused. an `ImageView` is just a UI widget. The widget is part of the layout and you cannot pass it from one `Activity` to another. You probably want to pass the actual image (a `Bitmap` or similar) from one `Activity` to another. To do this you can put the `Bitmap` in the `Intent` as an "extra", but if it is large, you probably want to store it somewhere and just pass a reference (URI, filename, etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.invalidate();
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then pass the byte array to the next activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("image", imageEncoded);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Get the byte from the intent second activity.

```
Bitmap bmp;

byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

Set the bitmap to the imageview of the second activty

imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: hallo thanks for the reply!
But this part is not working:

byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

it shows me a error in the code

Comment: Due to the following line:
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

it shows the following error:
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to byte[]

Comment: oops sorry! My bad. I have updated the answer please check the updated answer

Comment: There are no more errors but the programm  ist not working. Even it is not switching to the next activity.

Comment: Activity 1 looks like:
imageView.invalidate();
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, addNewClothes.class);
intent.putExtra("image", imageEncoded);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Activity 2 looks like:
 imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_image);

        Bitmap bmp;
        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: I think the Problem is how to declare the selected Image from my Internal Storage of my mobile into a bitmap or drawable element which can be than pass to the next activity via the line: intent.putExtra("image", bitmap or drawable);

Answer (score -1):

Don't pass imageview to next activity.

You can pass uri of  Image which is selected from gallery.\

Get Uri for selected image in `onActivityResult` method like below code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == SELECT_GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                imageSelectedFromGallery(data);
                pictureUri=data.getData();
                imageView_selectedImage.setImageURI(pictureUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note**:  make `pictureUri` `instance` variable instead of `local` variable.

Pass Image Uri to next Activity like below code:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,NextActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("pictureUri",pictureUri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Get Image Uri in Next Activity and set into imageView :

```
 ImageView imageview=findViewById(R.id.imageview);
 Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
 if(bundle!=null) {
      String pictureUri = bundle.getString("pictureUri");
      imageview.setImageURI( Uri.parse(pictureUri));
 }
```

I hope its work for you.